# Remove first element of MutableMap

Tags: android, kotlin

Have a Mutable Map like this

```
val orders: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<MenuItem>>
```

How can I delete first element of it or remove all by filter?

Comment: What do you mean by "first element" ? Because by design, a Map does not especially rely on any form of order. You are never guaranteed of any order when working with maps, hashmaps, etc.

Comment: I mean element that added earlier, but if it not possible please suggest how to remove by filter, thanks

Comment: Map is not ordered, it does not have first or last element.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if not ordered does it mean not have first element or it mean not guaranteed which element will be first?

Comment: you can't get elements of the map by index, as they don't have indexes. So the element just can't be *first* or *last*

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko orders.values.first() vill return first element as it written in documentation

Comment: yes, but that is not the first element of the map, but the first element of map's values list

Comment: `Map.entries.first` may also be used... still: that's not the first you added to the map... it's just any first entry found in the map... depending on the type of map, etc.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko and orders.keys.first() will return first key of map, and this all means Map have first element only it depended on the type of Map as Ronald said

Comment: According to the `Set` documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html), `Set` is  `unordered collection of elements`, which means that `first` will return random element. `keys` is a Set

Comment: If call first() on it multiple times does it will return different items randomly?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko If call first() on it multiple times does it will return different items randomly? If not, its mean it not random but depended from type of Map

Comment: I only know that it won't return the first element, but will return *any* element. Since you want to delete **first** element, it is not what you want. Probably you should store your items not in a map, but in a list instead. That way you will know, which element is first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the "remove all by filter" you may be interested in one of the following:

```
orders.entries.removeIf { /* your predicate */ }
orders.values.removeIf { /* your predicate */ }
orders.keys.removeIf { /* your predicate */ }
// and/or the extension function removeAll:
orders.entries.removeAll { /* your predicate */ }
orders.values.removeAll { /* your predicate */ }
orders.keys.removeAll { /* your predicate */ }
```

Regarding removing the first I assume you just want any (but at most 1) matching element to remove (not the actual first in a `Map`). You could probably just iterate/filter, take the first and then simply call `remove` for it..., e.g.:

```
val yourMatchingEntry = orders.entries.first { /* your predicate */ }
        .also { orders.entries.remove(it) }
```

This then just returns any (but 1) of the map entries which match your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove a certain number of elements from a map - didn't matter which ones. This worked for me:

```
orders.remove(orders.keys.first())
```

For removing all matching a filter, @Roland has given the various APIs you can use.
e.g. to remove all entries having empty list as value:

```
orders.entries.removeAll { it.value.isEmpty() }
```